# Advanced Filter - exclude headers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that does an Advanced Filter. How can I exclude the headers from this? I tried changing `C:C` to `C2:C` but it's not working.

```
Sub extractuniquevalues2()


Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wksSummary As Excel.Worksheet
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'edited so it shows in the 3rd column row +1.  Add the header and sheet name macro to this

On Error Resume Next
Set wksSummary = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
On Error GoTo 0

If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
    Set wksSummary = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
End If


'Iterate through all the worksheets, but skip [Summary] worksheet.
For Each wks In Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With wksSummary

        If wks.Name <> .Name Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wks.Range("C:C")) Then
                Call wks.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter(xlFilterCopy, , .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3), True)
            End If
        End If

    End With

Next wks


    End Sub
```

To show you a visual check my image: [img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/On3Gh.jpg

Would like to get rid of the headers and have the names row-by-row without spaces between.

**EDIT**------------------------------------------------------------------------

So i'm doing it like so, getting errors:

```
    Sub testage()


Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wksSummary As Excel.Worksheet
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'edited so it shows in the 3rd column row +1.  Add the header and sheet name macro to this

On Error Resume Next
Set wksSummary = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
On Error GoTo 0

If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
    Set wksSummary = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
End If


'Iterate through all the worksheets, but skip [Summary] worksheet.
For Each wks In Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets



    Dim r As Range

    ' Get the first cell of our destination range...
       Set r = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)

         ' Perform the unique copy...
           wks.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True

    'Remove the first cell at the destination range...
           r.Delete xlShiftUp



Next wks


   End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. All of the filter functions work with headers, even the ones where you copy to a new destination, such as in your case. But you can just follow-up with a `Delete xlShiftUp` to remove the first cell at your destination range and shift everything up a spot:

```
Dim r As Range

' Get the first cell of our destination range...
Set r = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)

' Perform the unique copy...
wks.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True

' Remove the first cell at the destination range...
r.Delete xlShiftUp
```

Comment: Hi @Bond, thank you for your advice. I tried to run this in a separate module and get the following error : Invalid or unqualified reference.  It highlights Rows on the set=r line.

Comment: I wrote this answer with the intention that you'd plug it in where your existing `AdvancedFilter` function is used, which is within a `With wksSummary` block.

Comment: I am doing it like how I did above(see Edit), is this correct? Keep getting errors.

Comment: No, you're leaving out quite a bit of your code. Just replace this line from your original snippet: `Call wks.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter(...)` with what I've shown.

Comment: Thanks Bond, you the best!