# Copying only unique values from one table to another moves over some duplicates

Tags: vba

So, I have a "narrow" table that I'm trying to turn into a "Wide" table. Alrighty, off to VBA we go to get this done in a reasonable amount of time. Let's get our keyID moved over first, and we only need unique values moved over. The code:

```
Sub Flatten()
Dim RawTable As ListObject
Dim FlatTable As ListObject
Dim SWS As Worksheet ' Source worksheet
Dim DWS As Worksheet ' Destination worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim HeaderCheck As Boolean
Dim FlatLastRow As Long
Dim MoveRange As Range
Dim LastColFlat As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set SWS = wb.Sheets("RawData")
Set DWS = wb.Sheets("Flattened Data")


HeaderCheck = wb.Names("HeaderIntegrityCheck").RefersToRange.Value2

If HeaderCheck Then
'Everything's good
Else
'Problem
MsgBox "Bad data entered into the RawData tab, headers aren't as expected. Please fix. The macro will now end"
End
End If

Set RawTable = SWS.ListObjects("RawTable")
Set FlatTable = DWS.ListObjects("FlatTable")
Set MoveRange = RawTable.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange

LastColFlat = DWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
FlatTable.Resize FlatTable.Range.Resize(CountUnique(MoveRange) + 1, LastColFlat)

MoveRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=FlatTable.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange, unique:=True



End Sub
```

The issue: The first two ID's will duplicate/not be unique. For example, 2155904666, 2155904666, 2155904659, 2155904659; will move over 2155904666, 2155904666, 2155904659. If I reverse it, I get  2155904659, 2155904659, 2155904666. This is happening with tiny datasets, with large datasets - the first two are always moving over. This also causes an error to trigger, since it properly counts how many unique IDs there are, and then tries to put one more line into the table.

Hack to fix: Have the resize be +2, test if the 1st data line is the same as the 2nd dataline, remove one of the lines if they are duplicates, then resize back down. This works, but it's clumsy and inelegant, and doesn't address the root cause of why moving over the values as unique isn't moving them over uniquely.

PS: If anyone has a better unique move method I'm all ears. Microsoft scripting library required to make the code run.

Comment: Advanced Filter always treats the first Value as a header.  I don't see anything in your code related to Scripting runtime.  Previously:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775564/advanced-filter-exclude-headers

Comment: So, in theory, if I grabbed the entire column including the header, and used it as the header of the destination, it should work out

Comment: Yes that should do it